# Display array of numbers with multicolor

Tags: android, dialog, android-custom-view

How can i display array of numbers with **multicolor in dialog**?

**Example:**

```
      arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5 , 6, 7, 8, 9}
```

And in dialog, display:

```
arr= 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

1 in red, 2 in blue, 3 in green,...
I try add Textview in RelativeLayout but til now, i don't know how?

Comment: use this library  https://github.com/blazsolar/FlowLayout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Spannable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable.html) allows you to add add such attributes.Here is small example have look at this.

```
TextView TV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mytextview01);
 Spannable word = new SpannableString(" 1");        

 word.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 0, word.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

 TV.setText(word);
 Spannable wordTwo = new SpannableString(" 2");        

 wordTwo.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, wordTwo.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
 TV.append(wordTwo);
```

**OR** :

You can also set the colors by using the Html.

```
String text = "<font color=#cc0029> 1</font> <font color=#ffcc00> 2</font>";
TV.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

Comment: I checked it. Sorry sir :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spannable. Setting ForegroundColorSpan you need to define color and chars interval, for example

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
    Spannable spannableText = new SpannableString("1 2 3");
    spannableText.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    spannableText.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN), 2, 3, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    spannableText.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 4, 5, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    textView.setText(spannableText);
```

Answer (score 0):

The provided solution will work, but it's bad form to use a string to represent a color when there is already a color resource type for this. Instead, do the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<color name="bright_pink">#FF007F</color>
<color name="red">#FF0000</color>
<color name="orange">#FF7F00</color>
<color name="yellow">#FFFF00</color>
<color name="chartreuse">#7FFF00</color>
<color name="green">#00FF00</color>
<color name="spring_green">#00FF7F</color>
<color name="cyan">#00FFFF</color>
<color name="azure">#007FFF</color>
<color name="blue">#0000FF</color>
<color name="violet">#7F00FF</color>
<color name="magenta">#FF00FF</color>

<array name="rainbow">
    <item>@color/bright_pink</item>
    <item>@color/red</item>
    <item>@color/orange</item>
    <item>@color/yellow</item>
    <item>@color/chartreuse</item>
    <item>@color/green</item>
    <item>@color/spring_green</item>
    <item>@color/cyan</item>
    <item>@color/azure</item>
    <item>@color/blue</item>
    <item>@color/violet</item>
    <item>@color/magenta</item>
</array>
```

Then access them like this:

```
int[] rainbow = context.getResources().getIntArray(R.array.rainbow);

for (int i = 0; i < tileColumns; i++) {
paint.setColor(rainbow[i]);
// Do something with the paint.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use StringBuilder Class for this:

```
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("arr = ");
 int[] arr = //this is your number array
 String[] colors = // this is your color array for eg. {"#ffffff",.....}
 for (int i;i<arr.length;i++) {
    sb.append("<font color="+colors[i]+">"+ Integer.toString(arr[i]) +"</font>");
 }
```

And while displaying the text your can use:

```
whereYouWantToDisplay.setText(Html.fromHtml(sb.toString()))
```

Hope This Helps.